# Newbie on linq to sql lambda expression where statement after two includes

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
    var Query2 = from x in CoreDatabase.Set<tblPerson>()
                 .Include(a => a.tblApplicationInterface.Select(b => b.tblApplicationName)
                 .Where(c => c.AppplicationName == "MshHumanResources"))

                 select x;
```

I get The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.


I am simply trying to write

Here something that works:

```
Select * 
From tblPerson a INNER JOIN tblApplicationInterface b 
on a.id = b.id
INNER Join tblApplicationName c
ON b.fkid=c.id
Where b.ApplicationName like 'MshHumanResources'
```

Comment: If you're trying to do that sql, why are you selecting out of the tblPerson set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how [`Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) works.  You want to use [`join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) instead:

```
var Query2 = from a in CoreDatabase.Set<tblPerson>()
             join b in CoreDatabase.Set<tblApplicationInterface>() on a.id equlas b.id
             join c in CoreDatabase.Set<tblApplicationName>() on b.fkid equals c.id
             where c.AppplicationName == "MshHumanResources"
             select a;
```

This is just selecting the columns from A - if you want to select columns from the other tables either create a class to combine the fields you need or use an anonymous type.

Comment: If I remove the where statement i get an inner join query with the statement above....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var Query2 = CoreDatabase.Set<tblPerson>
                 .Include("tblApplicationInterface")
                 .Include("tblApplicationInterface.tblApplicationName")
                 .Where(x => x.ApplicationName == "MshHumanResources");
```

Comment: I dont seem to be able to   .Include(x => x.tblApplicationInterface.tblApplicationName) that line

Comment: Maybe Linq to SQL doesn't allow lambda expressions as include arguments. I changed my answer to use literals.

Answer (score 0):

Directly, you could say

```
var people = CoreDatabase.Set<tblPerson>().Where( p => 
p.tblApplicationInterface.tblApplicationName.ApplicationName == "MshHumanResources" );
```

If I understand your navigation properties correctly. This would select people who's app interface's app name was MshHumanResources.

Comment: But it wouldn't load the data from tblApplicationIterface and tblApplicationName

Comment: True, at that point you'd only have a tblPerson object. If you wanted the navigation properties also filled in, you'd need the includes as in your answer. I think the where clause here is more accurate though, if I am reading the navigation properties correctly and remember how include works.

Comment: Actually, addendum, I think if you reference them, linq to sql will fill them in. However, as I recall include takes a string argument, not a lambda, so I'm not entirely sure what ORM this is referencing.

Comment: How come this works then             acct = DataContext.BrokerageAccounts
                .Include("tblPersons")
                .Include("tblApplicationInterface")
                .Include("tblApplicationInterface.tblApplicationName")
            .SingleOrDefault(ba => ba.ApplicationName == "MSH");